# How to update ModelAdmin variable on every page refresh?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have to fetch some data from external API and display it as columns in django admin page. I tried running code as assigning to a class-level variable but it only fetched data at the start of django server and it doesn't work as a function-level call, because somehow requests library freezes django here.

So both of these examples won't work for me:

```py
class NewModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    variable = requests.get(...) # it's executing only once
```

```
class NewModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def some_column(self, obj):
        variable = requests.get(...) # it's freezing the app
        ...
    some_column.short_description = 'Some Column'
    some_column.admin_order_field = 'some_column'
```

Comment: you need celery.

Comment: If you have 100 rows in your admin, obviously you're going to do 100 requests to the external API. These all have to be processed before the admin view can be shown. Seems like you have to try a completely different approach, like adding the column to your model and populate the values when the object is created (then only one call needs to be made).

Answer (score 0):

The call to `requests.get` is going to be syncronous, so it'll halt execution and tie up the Django process while it awaits a response. If you have tons of workers, or if you admin interface isn't used all that much, this might not be a problem. You can mitigate it by adding a timeout onto the request.

**Server Side**
If you're fine with it holding up the process, you can override the `__init__` method of the `ModelAdmin` to have it happen each time an instance of the modeladmin is created:

```
class NewModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    variable = requests.get(...) # it's executing only once

class NewModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewModelAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        intended_value = requests.get(...)  # Grab the value here
        self.fields['some_column'].short_description = intended_value
```

**Client Side**
If you're not okay with this holding up the process, you can add a Javascript file onto the page that does the API call for you, and then modifies the field description. This assumes you (or whoever owns the site whose resource you're grabbing) have CORS and authentication configured properly.

```
# admin.py
class NewModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ('myapp/script.js,')
```

```
# script.js
fetch('mysite.com/api/url')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then( /* change markup of field */ )
```

Comment: OP isn't just changing the description of a column, OP is actually adding a column, probably for every row a different value needs to be fetched.